# Are acyclic coverings cofinal in the set of coverings?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homology-cohomology, sheaf-theory

I am interested by the following question in algebraic geometry.

Recall that a covering $\mathfrak{U}$ of a topological space $X$ is acyclic for a sheaf $\mathscr{F}$ if we have $H^q(U_{i_0,\cdots, i_p},\mathscr{F})=0,$ for all $q>0$, where $H^*$ is in my case $\check{C}$ech cohomology (but it could be also more generally sheaf cohomology).

My question is : are acyclic coverings cofinal in the set of all coverings of $X$? More precisely, given any covering $\mathfrak{U}$, can we find a finer covering $\mathfrak{V}$ that is acyclic? If the question is not true in general, under which conditions is it true (if it is true)?

The question is motivated by a proof of Leray's Theorem (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leray%27s_theorem).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your restatement of cofinality is incorrect. You should ask, for any cover $\mathfrak{U}$, is there an acyclic covering that is finer than $\mathfrak{U}$? And the answer is no in general: there exist sheaves for which _no_ acyclic covering exists; see e.g. [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/93289/5191).

Comment: Thank you very much. But are there conditions under which this statement is true? For example, for a topological manifold?

Comment: I don't think there are reasonable restrictions on the space. But you would have better luck if you _also_ restrict the sheaves.

Comment: It seems that it is true for a topologcal manifold together with a (locally?) constant sheaf, since then the coverings becomes good covers in the sense of Bott/Tu, that are apparently cofinal (I am not sure of anything of this).  My confusion came from the fact that Godement in his book did not use such restrictions to prove a version of Leray's theorem. I miss maybe a point elsewhere. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You don't need to assume anything about cofinality to prove Leray's theorem. The Bott/Tu device of good covers will work for locally constant sheaves.

Comment: Grothendieck states in the Tohoku paper (Lemma 3.8.2) that for fixed $q$ and every open covering there exists an refinement, so that the $q$th sheaf cohomology on every set of this refinement vanishes.