# Does a complex manifold always admit an acyclic cover for the sheaf of holomorphic functions?

Tags: complex-geometry, sheaf-cohomology, complex-manifolds

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a sheaf on a topological space $X$. An open cover $\mathcal{U} = \{U_i\}_{i\in I}$ of $X$ is called *acyclic for* $\mathcal{F}$ if for all $i_0, \dots, i_p \in I$, $H^q(U_{i_0}\cap\dots\cap U_{i_q}, \mathcal{F}) = 0$ for every $q \geq 1$. Not every sheaf admits an acyclic cover as is shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/93192/39599).

Let $X$ be a complex manifold and consider the sheaf $\mathcal{O}$ of holomorphic functions on $X$. Does $X$ always admit an open cover which is acyclic for $\mathcal{O}$? What about for the sheaf $\mathcal{O}^*$ of nowhere zero holomorphic functions on $X$?

Comment: Michael, for starters, it seems like because of the Dolbeault Lemma (for the case of $\mathscr O$), you only need to consider an open cover by polydisks, as then intersections will likewise be polydisks. [This would be the analogue of geodesically convex coverings of a Riemannian manifold.] I think you ought to be able to deduce that it will work for $\mathscr O^*$ as well, but I haven't thought this through.

Comment: I don't think the intersection of polydiscs is necessarily a polydisc. For example, $(D(0, 1)\times D(0, 1))\cap(D(1, 1)\times D(0, 1))$ is not a polydisc. Is the intersection of polydiscs necessarily biholomorphic to a polydisc? If so, then as $H^q(\cdot, \mathcal{O}) = H^{0,q}_{\bar{\partial}}(\cdot)$ and the latter is a biholomorphism invariant, we can conclude that a covering by polydiscs is an acyclic cover for $\mathcal{O}$.

Comment: Michael: I've given away my Gunning and Rossi (which is where I would have looked). But in the proof of Lemma 5.3.9 of Neeman's *Algebraic and Analytic Geometry* he argues that the intersection of generalized polydisks is a generalized polydisk; a generalized polydisk is the preimage of a polydisk under a polynomial mapping, so we're not quite there, but ...

Comment: I haven't been able to find anything in Gunning and Rossi, but I am not familiar with the book so I might be looking in the wrong place. I have read the proof of Lemma 5.3.9, but I have no intuition about generalised polydiscs, in particular, their biholomorphism type. Was your ellipsis an indication that I should be able to arrive at a conclusion from your remarks or just a trailing thought?

Comment: Dear Michael, the intersection of two polydiscs is most certainly not isomorphic to a polydisc: it needn't even be connected! You can check that already in $\mathbb C$, where any simply connected open subset distinct from $\mathbb C$ is isomorphic to a (poly)disc, according to Riemann's uniformization theorem. However the intersection of two polydiscs is Stein: see my answer.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg: Sorry, I can't see why what you've said is true. As discs are convex and products of convex sets are convex, a polydisc is convex. The intersection of convex sets is convex and hence (path-)connected, so the intersection of polydiscs is connected. Am I missing something? Also, in $\mathbb{C}$, the intersection of two discs is convex, so it is connected and simply connected. Therefore, if the intersection of discs is non-empty, it is biholomorphic to the unit disc by the Uniformisation Theorem.

Comment: Dear Michael, "polydisc" in an abstract complex manifold means biholomorphically isomorphic to a standard polydisc in $\mathbb C^n$. What else could it mean in Ted's first comment (or in your own question) , which is about  coverings of a manifold  by open subsets ? Convexity (in the affine sense) doesn't make sense in a manifold. Apologies if that  terminology caused some misunderstanding.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg: Sorry, I wasn't aware of this convention; to me, the word polydisc indicates a product of discs. With this more general definition, your initial comment makes sense. Is connectivity the only obstruction to having the intersection of polydiscs (using the general definition) be isomorphic to a polydisc? It is in dimension one.

Comment: Dear @Michael, I don't see why the intersection of two such generalized polydiscs in a manifold, even if assuymed connected, should be a third polydisc, but I have no counter-example to present...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $X$ is a complex space, not necessarily a manifold nor even reduced, **any** cover $\mathcal U=(U_i)_{i\in I}$ by open subsets $U$ which are Stein is acyclic for any coherent sheaf.
Indeed any finite intersection $U=U_1\cap\dots\cap U_n $ of sets $U\in \mathcal U$ is Stein : this is trivial if you define "Stein" as holomorphically convex and holomorphically separable.
But is it legitimate to define "Stein" that way?
Sure! That's what the brothers Ludger and Burchard Kaup do in their extremely pedagogical book [Holomorphic functions of Several Variables](http://books.google.fr/books/about/Holomorphic_Functions_of_Several_Variabl.html?id=nDgBsOurnAIC&redir_esc=y)
One may say that the basic theory of Stein spaces consists of proving (in about 100 pages!) the equivalence of several definitions of Stein spaces, in particular the one that says that a Stein space is a complex space for which theorem B holds!

**Reminders/complements**
1) A complex space $Y$ is said to be holomorphically  convex if, given a  compact subset $K\subset Y$, its holomorphic hull $h(K)$ is also compact.
That hull is defined as the set of $y\in Y$ such that for all $f\in \mathcal O(Y)$ we have $\mid f(y)\mid\leq \sup_{k\in K} \mid f(k)\mid$
A (non-trivially!) equivalent definition of holomorphically convex is:
Given a discrete closed subset $D\subset Y$, there exists a holomorphic function $h\in \mathcal O(Y)$ such that $\sup_{d\in D} \mid h(d)\mid=\infty$.

2) A complex space $Y$ is said to be holomorphically  separable if, given $y\neq y'\in Y$,  there exists $g \in \mathcal O(Y)$ with $g(y)\neq g(y')$ .

3) Very roughly one might divide complex analysis into  two parts:
$\bullet$ The kingdom of partial differential equations  with its emphasis on plurisubharmonicity, pseudoconvexity, $L^2$-estimates, $\bar {\partial}$-operator, $\dots$ The basic book here is Hörmander's.
$\bullet \bullet$ The kingdom of geometry and algebra with its emphasis on sheaves, homological and commutative algebra, non-reduced spaces, algebraic topology, $\dots$
The  Kaups's book and the above answer are  written  in the spirit of this second point of view (I used holomorphic convexity instead of pseudoconvexity) , which is more adapted to the study of the  general non reduced complex spaces introduced by Grauert under the influence of Grothendieck.
The definitive reference on Stein spaces written by Grauert-Remmert, the masters themselves, [Theory of Stein spaces](https://books.google.fr/books?id=6uYlBQAAQBAJ&pg=PR5&lpg=PR5&dq=grauert+remmert+stein+spaces&source=bl&ots=gzV5G7ggpg&sig=UFIcgnillDXEA54XRiZ0g1QDLl0&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=SL4wVfefCcPT7QbMw4CgAg&ved=0CGEQ6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q=grauert%20remmert%20stein%20spaces&f=false) doesn't even mention plurisubharmonicity and pseudoconvexity (although, needless to say, these are extremely useful tools in many contexts).

4) How do I know this? Because in my youth I betrayed the first Kingdom for the second and then I betrayed the second for the Scheming Empire of Algebraic Geometry...

Comment: So a covering by Stein manifolds is acyclic for any coherent sheaf by Cartan's Theorem B, in particular for the sheaf $\mathcal{O}$. What about $\mathcal{O}^*$? Is it a coherent sheaf?

Comment: No, it isn't, so that a covering by Stein open sets has no reason to be acyclic for $\mathcal O^*$, unfortunately.

Answer (score 5):

OK, so what you want is [H. Cartan's Theorem B](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartan%27s_theorems_A_and_B), which states that whenever $X$ is a closed analytic subvariety of a polydisk and $\mathscr F$ is a coherent sheaf, then $H^i(X,\mathscr F) = 0$ for $i>0$. This should be in Gunning and Rossi. :)

Trying again (darn, I'm rusty on this stuff):  Any polydisk is a simple example of a domain of holomorphy in $\Bbb C^n$. The preimage under an analytic map of a domain of holomorphy is again a domain of holomorphy (Theorem 2.5.14 of Hörmander's *Introduction to Complex Analysis in Several Variables*), and intersections of domains of holomorphy are again domains of holomorphy (Corollary 2.5.7). Moreover, the big theorem (Theorem 4.2.8) tells us that domains of holomorphy are equivalent to pseudoconvex domains. And the $\overline\partial$ problem is always solvable in pseudoconvex domains. [I'm sure there are more basic ways to get this ...]

Perhaps an easier way, avoiding polydisks, is to put a hermitian metric on the complex manifold and (as in the smooth manifold case), cover with sufficiently small geodesic balls. It should be the case that these are pseudoconvex, and then we're back in business, intersections being again pseudoconvex.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but why is the intersection of polydiscs a closed subvariety of a polydisc?

Comment: Dear Michael, I'm not sure this is true but it doesn't matter: the intersection of two polydiscs is Stein and Theorem B holds for all Stein manifolds.